# Finding difference in dates by grouped variable

Tags: r, date, group-by

I am working on my Master's Thesis and need help with some R coding. I am analyzing movements of wild turkeys during different stages of reproduction. I need to find the difference in the last date and the first date that an individual was within an area.

```
x<- data.frame(
AreaID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2),
Timestamp=as.POSIXct(c("06/01/2014 05:01", "6/01/2014 13:00","06/01/2014 23:00", "06/02/2014 10:00","06/20/2015 09:00",
"06/20/2015 10:00", "06/20/2015 11:00", "06/20/2015 12:00"), format='%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))
```

I need a new dataframe with AreaID and the time spent in that area.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `dplyr` solution from @Gregor should work. However, if `dplyr` is not functioning properly. You can try the approach using `data.table`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(x)
x[, .(duration = max(Timestamp) - min(Timestamp)), by = AreaID]
   AreaID      duration
1:      1 1.207639 days
2:      2 3.000000 days
```

Or use the `aggregate` function from the base R.

```
aggregate(Timestamp ~ AreaID, data = x, FUN = function(x) max(x) - min(x))
  AreaID Timestamp
1      1 1.207639 
2      2 3.000000
```

#### Update

To make the unit of time consistent, we can use the `difftime` function with `units` argument, which could be "hours", "days" or other units.

```
aggregate(Timestamp ~ AreaID, data = x, 
          FUN = function(x) difftime(max(x), min(x), units = "hours"))

  AreaID Timestamp
1      1 28.98333 
2      2  3.00000
```

Comment: I am still having trouble with dplyr so i used the aggregate function which worked but some data is returned in hours and some data is returned in days. Is there any way to return all the data in one format? Hours or days doesn't really matter as long as it is all in the same units.

Comment: Please see my updates. We can use the `difftime` function.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(dplyr)
group_by(x, AreaID) %>%
    summarize(duration = max(Timestamp) - min(Timestamp))
# # A tibble: 2 x 2
#   AreaID      duration
#    <dbl>        <time>
# 1      1 1.207639 days
# 2      2 3.000000 days
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am having an issue with dplyr. When I run the above code, R Studio crashes and leaves the follwing error: "This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information."

Comment: First make sure your packages are up to date (`update.packages`), if it persists try re-installing RStudio.